# How handle multiple inputs from one form in PHP

Tags: php, html

I'm not sure how to ask this question. It procedural question I believe.

```
<input type="hidden" name="1[]" value="dummy">
<input type="radio" name="1[]" value="5">
<label> Very Good </label>
<input type="radio" name="1[]" value="4">
<label> Good </label>
<input type="text" name="1[]" size="20">
<br>
<input type="hidden" name="2[]" value="dummy">
<input type="radio" name="2[]" value="5">
<label> Very Good </label>
<input type="radio" name="2[]" value="4">
<label> Good </label>
<input type="text" name="2[]" size="20">
```

$_POST output:

```
 [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Text misc
        )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 5
        [1] => 
    )
```

From this I construct and INSERT statement.

```
INSERT INTO coached_tracked (coached_id, value, note) 
VALUES ($key, $value[0], $value[1]);
```

This is are dynamically generated form inputs. A radio button, text field pair.

How can I handle an occurrence where the radio is not selected and the text field has value, like in the first instance. I want the option of having nothing selected so a default value seems not called for. I tried with both with and without a dummy value (I saw an example suggesting a hidden field as a possible solution.)

Suggestions.

Comment: I think you are confused about what putting `[]` at the end of an input name actually does. Think of it like an array. When you submit a form, it takes all of the form elements with the same name before the brackets, and then any that are selected, checked or contain a value (even if it's empty), will be added to a zero-indexed array and sent to the server. How you have it now it would be practically impossible to tell what is going on server-side because you just get a zero indexed array of any values, but you can't tell which one it comes from.

Comment: Also, having two form elements with exactly the same name is not allowed (i.e. without using `[]`). I think that's what you're trying to do.

Comment: The reason for using the same name arrays is to use the name as an id key for the database insert. The radio and text pair make up one item/id. The radio value and text value are values belonging to the id item being tracked.  Maybe my process is faulty. But this was the way I thought I could do this. But I ran into my posted problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not tell the database what ID to use. Let the database itself determine that by using an auto-incremented column.

First, start with a logical input name. Using just numbers is extremely confusing and looking at your code, I have absolutely no idea what you're doing. We also want everything to go into the same PHP `$_POST` variable to not have to iterate over all possible number cominations. That means we can just iterate over the one single array.

Let's say you're adding a coach to a database, so logically we would start with:

```
<input name="coach">
```

Now when we want to add multiple coaches instead of just one, we can use HTML array names, however I would recommend you hard-code them instead of auto-incrementing in your HTML, which should simplify things later on. We also pluralize it to `coaches`:

```
<?php
for ($i=0;$i<10;$i++) {
    ?>
    <input name="coaches[<?=$i?>]">
    <?php
}
```

Now if each coach contains a certain properties, let's say `name`, `salary`, `note`,  etc, we can add the properties to the input names like so:

```
<?php
for ($i=0;$i<10;$i++) {
    ?>
    <input name="coaches[<?=$i?>][name]">
    <input name="coaches[<?=$i?>][salary]">
    <input name="coaches[<?=$i?>][note]">
    <?php
}
```

Then in PHP you just iterate over `$_POST['coaches']` and then use the properties for each coach how you wish:

```
if (isset($_POST['coaches'])) {
    foreach ($_POST['coaches'] as $coach) {
        $name = $coach['name'];
        $salary = $coach['salary'];
        $note = $coach['note'];

        // Now execute the query:
        // INSERT INTO coached_tracked (name, salary, note) 
        // VALUES ($name, $salary, $note);
    }
}
```

Note: remember to sanitize any user-supplied data by using prepared statements with bound parameters to make sure you're not open to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The coached_id is the name of the item and could very easily be referred to as coached_name. I allow the database to auto create the id. The number is a reference to a fuller description in a different table. What I believe I can't figure out is a method to handle two inputs for the same database item. In this case a radio value and text field value for a singular coached_id (or coached_item_name). Maybe that makes the question clearer??? Thanks again.

Comment: I've edited my answer. It's simply a matter of looping over the values you get from the browser.

Comment: May I ask what is the <?$i?> syntax? I have never seen that before. I think I see what you are suggesting here. I'm going to study this. Thanks.

Comment: `<?=$i?>` is the same as `<?php echo $i; ?>`.

Comment: Is it considered bad form to ask a follow up question to this? The iterate code will note initialize the variables (e.g. $name, $salary). It seems the notation  <input name="coaches[<?=$i?>]['name']"> with the key 'name' in quotes causes it not to be available to assign with the $coach['name'];. I had to remove the single quotes. Then it worked. As I'm just learning I don't know which is correct. Again, thanks for your earlier solution. I works and I learned a good bit.

Comment: You're right. I shouldn't have had the single quotes. Force of habit.